# PowerBI Premium connect Server Analysis Service

Tags: powerbi

Good morning,

I am working with PowerBI premium and I am looking to connect a datasets existing in a premium workspace.
I need to connect to SQL Server Analysis services using the following connection string:
powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/workspacename;initial catalog=report_name

It works when connecting from PowerBI desktop but I am unable to connect to the datasets when I publish my report in the same workspace as the datasets.

The purpose of using SQL Server Analysis service instead of "Connect to PowerBI Datasets" is that I can work locally.
2 files:

- 1 datasets (Model)
- 1 report connected through "localhost:PortNumber"

When ready I can publish my datasets, then change datasets connection string in my report file and finally I can publish the report online for consumption.

Would someone know how I can do that without having an error after publishing the report online?